# Why does this rvalue reference bind to an lvalue?

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer, rvalue-reference, decltype

I do not understand why the following code compiles on GCC 8.0:

```
decltype(auto) foo(int&& r) {
    return r;
}
```

In `foo`, the declaration type of `r` is `int&&`, and so the return type of `foo` is also `int&&`. But `r` itself is an lvalue, and an lvalue  cannot bind to an rvalue reference.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Reproduced with [gcc8](https://wandbox.org/permlink/4CSGrHnZ26nGL8QK), it seems gcc8 deduced the return type to be `int&`.

Comment: @songyuanyao They claim the code compiles, so that would be no repro.

Comment: @BaummitAugen The fixed code compiles with [gcc8](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7mUFIa2VVAwgprEM), but not [clang6](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3lpIoyciSWUisYh7).

Comment: @songyuanyao Now that's more interesting.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Yes I'm curious too; I guess it's gcc's bug.

Comment: @songyuanyao  sorry for the confusion; `foo` should not compile for reasons given in the question

Comment: Seems like a GCC bug indeed. Note however that if you were to return a parenthesized id expression (`return (r);`, it would work by design).

Comment: @curiousguy12: As an aside, welcome to StackOverflow. Great first question, we need more people like you around.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to [[dcl.spec.auto]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec.auto#dcl.type.auto.deduct-5), the return type is deduced as if the `return` statement's operand was the operand of `decltype`. And [[dcl.type.simple]/(4.2)](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.simple#4.2) clearly states that, as the operand is not parenthesized, the type of the entity is the type yielded by `decltype`, that is, `int&&`. And indeed, `r` is an lvalue ([[expr.prim.id.unqual]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id.unqual#1)).

Fortunately, this has been discovered and filed as [bug 64892](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64892) two years ago. (I wonder why no one could find the time to fix this?)